# How to get a reference in a struct of the same struct in my code

Tags: c++, struct

I have this struct, but I get some errors when I mention a reference to its own type:

```
struct Point  {
              int x;
              int y;

              bool isLattice;

              Vect2D gradient;

              ///used only when isLattice is false
              Point p00; ///top-left corner
              Point p01; ///top-right corner
              Point p10; ///bottom-left corner
              Point p11; ///bottom-right corner

              ///the displacement vectors  Gradient-this.Vect2D
              Vect2D disp00;
              Vect2D disp01;
              Vect2D disp10;
              Vect2D disp11;  ///used along the gradient vector of the lattice points

              ///the Q-s for each corner Q= Disp*G which are going to be used for the interpolation
              double q00;
              double q01;
              double g10;
              double q11;

          };
```

I need to know how I should initialize this struct, because this is how I used to do it in the past in other codes. What is the error in this one?

Comment: I suppose telling us what the errors are, and how you are initialising it would be too much to ask?

Comment: When I try to initialize Point p00 for example , it says it has incomplete type

Comment: You must have done that in a different language. Such a structure would be infinitely large in C++.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you're coming from a managed language

```
struct Point  {
    //...
    Point p00; 
    // ...
}
```

This is your problem. Objects in C++ are **NOT** references. This puts an instance of Point inside an instance of Point. How will that work? You could use a pointer, or a reference.

Change

```
Point p00;
```

to

```
Point & p00; // this requires being initialized  
             // in the constructor initialization list
```

or maybe

```
std::shared_ptr<Point> p00;
```

Comment: If you haven't already, get [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1) and forget everything you know about whatever language you already know.

Comment: I'd pitch a `std::unique_ptr` over the `std::shared_ptr`. Doesn't seem to be any need to share ownership.

Comment: @user4581301 It appeared to me that the pointers were coming from somewhere else, so ownership was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Point pX;` to `Point * pX;`.

This way, the code will compile, and you 
get to initialise the Point pointers using an appropriate constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use another type struct in instances of Point?